# Generic type parameter error

Tags: c#, generics

I have these 3 abstract classes:

```
public abstract class DataObject {}
public abstract class BusinessObject<T> where T : DataObject {}
public abstract class UIObject<T> where T : BusinessObject<DataObject> {}
```

I am able to create a **CustomerDataObject** which derives from `DataObject`, a **CustomerBusinessObject** which derives from `BusinessObject<CustomerDataObject>` but I can't create the **CustomerUIObject** class:

> The type `CustomerBusinessObject` cannot be used as type parameter `T`
>   in the generic type or method `UIObject<T>`. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from `CustomerBusinessObject` to
>   `BusinessObject<DataObject>`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tom Orton describes why this doesn't work, but the proper solution to this problem depends on how you want to use these types (and the their type parameters).  If you post more details of your use case, we might be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: @WillVousden For example, the BusinessObject abstract class exposes some methods and events that are shared between all specific business objects. In this case I need the generic type parameter because the DataObject associated with the BusinessObject needs to be accessible, so it exposes this property: `public abstract T DataObject { get; protected set; }`

Comment: But how does a `UIObject` interact with its type parameters?  It seems like it might only need to know the `DataObject`-derived type (from which it could construct the `BusinessObject` type itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Why`  - you already know

Now there is a way that you can do it - without changing logic :

You can add **double** constraint :

```
public abstract class DataObject {}
public abstract class BusinessObject<T> where T : DataObject {}
public abstract class UIObject<T,U> where T : BusinessObject<U> where U:DataObject {}
```

This way you explicitly tell the compiler that `U` can be a type that derive from `DataObject`  - which is exactly what your `CustomerDataObject` is.

But you will need to add :

```
class CustomerDataObject:DataObject
{}
class CustomerBusinessObject :BusinessObject<CustomerDataObject>
{}
class CustomerUIObject :UIObject<CustomerBusinessObject,CustomerDataObject>
{}
```

This way you're specifying the `CustomerDataObject` which inherits from `DataObject` which is exactly what you meant at  first place

Comment: Thank you, it works, though it is a bit of an eyesore. Would you consider this approach a bad practice?

Comment: It really depends on the actual situation. In general this is what generic constraints are good at.Type safety. All my code is doing here is telling the compiler  : Hey - Please allow `BusinessObject<CustomerDataObject>` to be recognized in  `where T : BusinessObject<DataObject> {}`

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitly stating that the T for `UIObject` inherits `BusinessObject<DataObject>` but your type `CustomerBusinessObject` actually inherits `BusinessObject<CustomerDataObject>` which is a different type.

Can you have `CustomerBusinessObject` inherit `BusinessObject<DataObject>` but then in the implementation always use `CustomerDataObject`? That would fix this error but might not be quite what you want.

```
public class CustomerBusinessObject : BusinessObject<DataObject> { }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use Generics contraints to resolve this issue.

```
public abstract class UIObject<T,U> where T : BusinessObject<U>
```

Comment: The compiler complains about boxing conversion, I added  ``where U : DataObject`` and it worked.

Comment: Yes....I actually added that when originally answered but thought parent class is anyway doing constraint check for DataObject so edited it.....Thanks for letting me know about the error.